# set dotnet core version using azure cli in azure windows webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

We have windows webapp in Azure, we want to change the stack to dotnet core version(3.1,2.1) using Azure cli.
If it is a linux webapp, we can use `az webapp config set -g $group -n $webappName --linux-fx-version "DOTNETCORE|2.1"`. But for windows couldn't find anything. Help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below powershell script, am able to achieve this.

```
Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName 'MyRG' -Name 'MyWebApp' -AppServicePlan ' MyWebAppPlan'
$PropertiesObject = @{"CURRENT_STACK" = "dotnetcore"}
New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName 'MyRG' -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config/metadata -ResourceName 'MyWebApp' -ApiVersion 2021-03-01 -Force
```

Refer this github issue for more information:- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21192

Answer (score 2):

In our local environment(webapp is running on Windows app service plan), using the below cmdlet initially we have changed the `.Net` version to 6.0

```
az webapp config set -g "<RGName>" -n "<WebAppName>" --net-framework-version "v6.0"
```

[image]

later, we have downgraded the version(v4.0) using the below cmdlet & we are able to get the **.NetCore(3.1,2.1)** in our webapp configuration.

```
 az webapp config set -g "<RGName>" -n "WebAppName>" --net-framework-version "v4.0"
```

[image]

Comment: v4.0 is changing it to ASP.NETv4.8. Thanks for the try.

Comment: I have updated my answer with output in GIF Please refer & If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response. one last question though, can you check if your webapp is windows/linux based. Because linux based doesn't support ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: @SrinivasB, please refer [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8DInPYb.png) my web app is windows based

Comment: still this doesn't work.